# Creating Hexagon layers with hexagon prefabs from the center point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to the C# coding, and was wondering if there's a way to generate prefabricated tiles of hexagon based on the layer needed from the center hexagon.

I am currently trying to create a 4 layers of hex from the center.

Most approaches I have seen is row and column which wont generate the shape I want (like in the picture provided), and they ***don't start from the middle.***

[image: example]

I am looking for an algorithm that would work on however many layers you want to set on the editor.

Comment: please give a  check on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8